# Passing a string argument to another string

Tags: c++, string

I have this class defined:

```
class Forum{
std::string title;
Thread* threads[5];
```

and in the constructor of Forum::Forum I want to pass a string argument to define title(which is of type-string)

```
Forum::Forum(string *k) {
int i;
std::strcpy(&title.c_str(),k->c_str());
```

I have problems in that.In this code i get an "lvalue required as unary '&' operand" error.
If i erase '&' i get the error " invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]".

Any ideas how I will manage to pass the argument with strcpy(or with another method maybe) to a string type avoiding the above errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you intend to allow the title to be omitted, I would recommend you pass a `const` reference instead of a pointer:

```
 Forum::Forum(const string& k)
```

This makes it more clear that the name must be provided and also allows passing a string literal as the name:

```
 Forum f("Main Forum");
```

Then, to copy a `std::string`, simply assign it or use its copy constructor. `strcpy` is only for C-style `char*` strings. In this case, use a member initializer:

```
Forum::Forum(const string& k):
  title(k)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use `strcpy` - as this will not work

Use the strings assignment operator

i.e.

```
Forum::Forum(string *k) {
    title = *k; 
}
```

Or better still

```
Forum::Forum(const string& k) {
    title = k; 
}
```

Or perhaps initialisation lists

```
Forum::Forum(const string& k) : title(k) { }
```

The latter being the best

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely learn a bit more about the Standard Library. In C++ you can assign one `std::string` to another without messing with pointers and `strcpy`.

```
Forum::Forum(const std::string& k) {
    // int i; you aran't using this anywhere, so why declare it?
    // as pointed out by @EdHeal, this-> is not necessary here
    /*this->*/ title = k; 
}
```

Comment: You do not need `this->` and also `int i` as `i` is never used

Comment: @EdHeal, maybe this is a part of code where `i` is used actually... Although you're right

Comment: `std::string` is not part of STL. STL is containers, iterators, and algorithms. Unfortunately, there is a trend toward using "STL" as shorthand for "STandard Library" when "Standard Library" is perfectly adequate and much more descriptive.